# Create a timestamp range between two different columns

Tags: sql, timestamp, where-clause

I am trying to create a query and in the where clause I want to have a **timestamp range** between two different timestamp columns(starttime & endtime). I tried this but it  fetched 0 results:

```
select *
from db.db_users
where ('<user_start_date>' >= starttime and '<user_end_date>' <= endtime)
and username ilike '%thodoris%'
limit 5;
```

*user_start_date* & *user_end_date* supposed to be user's values and different between them:
e.g.(2020-07-10 00:00:00 & 2020-07-10 23:59:59).

I want to ask if there is any other way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should be using parameters.  Second, the logic for a *complete* overlap is:

```
where start_date < :user_start_date and
      end_date > :user_end_date
```

And for a partial overlap:

```
where start_date < :user_send_date and
      end_date > :user_start_date
```